# Monthly Sales using two datetimepickers

Tags: .net, winforms, datetimepicker

I have two datetimepicker and one button
I want sales of monthly or wahtever date selected in two datetimepickers

Below is my query:

```
ad2 = New SqlDataAdapter(
        "select sum(amt) from TailorLedger where date between'" &
        CDate(DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString) &
        "' AND '" &
        CDate(DateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString) &
        "'", con)
```

But on button press it shows following error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Can anyone suggest the correct query?

Answer (score 0):

You should always parameterize your SQL queries to avoid [SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx).

Once you have used strong typing on the SQL parameters you should be able to solve  the problem you are seeing. To start you off, here's a snippet (not compiled or tested):

```
 SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter("select sum(amt) from TailorLedger where date between @par1 and @par2", connection);
  myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@par1", SqlDbType.DateTime);
  myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters["@par1"].Value = yourFirstDate;
  myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@par2", SqlDbType.DateTime);
  myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters["@par2"].Value = yourSecondDate;
```

If this is still not working, you should investigate the culture being used, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141272/cdate-function-using-different-locales) for more details.